# Surjectively isometric normed spaces: Hamel vs (extended) Schauder dimension

Tags: isometries, norms, banach-spaces

Bonjour/bonsoir à toutes et à tous.

This may really be a very basic question, but... Let $\mathbf{X} \equiv (X, \|\cdot\|_X)$ and $\mathbf{Y} \equiv (Y, \|\cdot\|_Y)$ be surjectively isometric (1) *normed* spaces (over the real or the complex field).

> **Question 1.** Do $\mathbf{X}$ and $\mathbf{Y}$ need to share the same Hamel
>   dimension?

The answer is clearly yes if the scalar field is the real numbers, since then any surjective isometry $\mathbf{X} \to \mathbf{Y}$ is, a fortiori, an affine transformation $X \to Y$ (via the Mazur-Ulam theorem). But what about the complex case?

---

**Added later.** As pointed out in the comments below, the answer to Question 1 is still yes if $\mathbf{X}$ and $\mathbf{Y}$ are (real or complex) Banach spaces essentially because the Hamel dimension of an infinite-dimensional (real or complex) Banach space is always at least the cardinality of the continuum (even if the CH fails) as proved in H. E. Lacey, *The Hamel Dimension of any Infinite Dimensional Separable Banach Space is c*, The American Mathematical Monthly, Vol. 80 (1973), p. 298 ([click](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2318458)). This is why I resolved to edit the OP and drop the earlier assumption on the completeness of $\mathbf{X}$ and $\mathbf{Y}$.

---

> **Question 2.** Now assuming that $\mathbf{X}$ and $\mathbf{Y}$ are Banach, do they need to share the same (extended) Schauder
>   dimension as defined in J. W. Evans
>   and R. A. Tapia, *Hamel Versus Schauder
>   Dimension*, The American Mathematical
>   Monthly, Vol. 77, No. 4 (Apr., 1970),
>   pp. 385-388 ([click](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2316148))?

**Notes.** (1) I'm using the term *isometry* to refer, herein, to both linear and non-linear isometries.

Comment: As to the first question, isn't the real case sufficient? A complex vector space is also a real vector space by restriction of the scalar field, and the real Hamel dimension (finite or not) is twice the complex Hamel dimension.

Comment: Also, isn't the Hamel dimension of a (real or complex) infinite dimensional Banach space equal to its cardinality?

Comment: As for question 1, there is an article by J. Bourgain, *Real isomorphic complex Banach spaces need not be complex isomorphic*, in Proc. AMS, vol 96, n.2 (1986) where an example is given of two complex Banach spaces which are isometric but not linearly isomorphic (over complex numbers). I don't remember the details, so I'm not sure it has really something to do with your question, but it could be a start.

Comment: @Pietro. You're absolutely right with your 2nd comment! The key point is that the Hamel dimension of an $\infty$-dimensional (real or complex) Banach space cannot be less than $|\mathbb{R}|$ (even if the CH fails!) as proved in H. E. Lacey, *The Hamel Dimension of any Infinite Dimensional Separable Banach Space is $\mathfrak{c}$*, The AMM, Vol. 80 (1973), p. 298. I confess, this is somehow surprising for me as I really thought the answer should not depend on the completeness of the space, and I'm editing the OP accordingly to pose the question in the *right* (normed) setting.

Comment: *Note.* By error, I deleted my previous comment (dated 25 Aug 2011). Now, I've tried to remember what it should be and posted it again. Sorry for the inconvenience!

@Samuele. Not really what I was seeking, but still useful. Thanks!

Comment: @Pietro Majer. I'm not yet convinced with your 1st comment on the finite dimensional case. Let `$\mathbf{X} \equiv (X, \|\cdot\|)$` be a complex normed space. Of course, we agree that $X$ can be as well regarded as a real *vector* space, and indeed `$\dim_\mathbb{R}(X) = 2\, \dim_\mathbb{C}(X)$`. But I'm not so sure that $\mathbf{X}$ can also be seen as a real *normed* space (essentially because $|a|+|b| \ne |a+ib|$ for arbitrary $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$). What do I miss here? Still, as you pointed out below, the finite dimensional case is settled by looking at the Hausdorff-Besicovitch dimension.

Comment: The norm of the complex normed space X also makes X a real normed space, when we restrict the field of scalars.

Comment: Actually, Evans&Tapia's paper does not claim that all separable Banach spaces do have "extended Schauder basis". I suspect it's not true indeed. In this case, question 2 has to be reformulated. Maybe assume that X and Y have an extended basis. I also implicitly assumed this in my answer, that however now I withdraw as less interesting. 

Comment: Also I forgot to say that the question may be of interest in the hypothesis of homeomorphic X and Y; as you observed if the normed spaces X and Y are assumed to be isometric, by Mazur-Ulam theorem they are actually linearly isometric, and they share whatever (real)normed-space-theoretic notion of dimension you like.

Comment: @Pietro Majer. Sorry for the big delay in replying! I was indeed sloppy in many respects, let's take this step-by-step. First, the question about the "realisation" of a complex normed space (btw, is there a standard naming for referring to this process? We have the term _complexification_ for the dual one, but I'm not aware of any analogue). Finally, I agree that it's enough to deal with the real case (for gloomy reasons, I thought that some _extra_ compatibility between the original norm and the one obtained by restriction of the scalar field should have been necessary for this to work).

Comment: As a consequence, you're decidedly right with your last remark too, and the original question is no longer that interesting (at least, as is). Also, your guess is right - I was implicitly assuming the existence of an (extended) Schauder basis. Now, what's the right way to go in this case? Should I edit the OP and update it accordingly? Or would it be better to open a new topic?